# I cannot install MongoDB because of dbpath

Tags: mongodb, database-installation

while installing MongoDB on my windows 7 64-bit, when I execute command

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data
```

it gives me error  that switch `dbpath` is not recognized and when I check in its help, I really cannot find this `--dbpath` switch.

any help where i'm doing mistake?

Comment: `mango` != `mongo`... And if the switch is not accepted and not documented, maybe you should start looking around for what the proper option to use is...

Answer (score 0):

It looks right, on my system (windows 10) the following command line works to set up up as a windows service.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath "C:\mongodata\db" --logpath "C:\mongodata\log\mongo.log" --serviceName yourname --serviceDisplayName "your description" --install
```

from the help:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe -help
```

```
  --dbpath arg                  directory for datafiles - defaults to \data\db\
                                which is D:\data\db\ based on the current 
                                working drive
```